# Android LayoutWidth being disregarded by cascaded use of LayoutInflater

Tags: android

I am building a pyramid of buttons and want the size of the pyramid to be able to change dynamically.  To accomplish this, I have extremely basic XML files representing the activity, each row of the activity, and each button.  I am modeling the solution from the accepted response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216811/creating-dynamic-view-multiple-a-view-x-times-get-set-value-for-each-group/2216844#2216844).  The pyramid constructs correctly, but the 50dip button width is not being adhered to.  Any ideas why?  Is there a better way of doing this?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pyramid" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/row"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

btn.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Main Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inflate();
    }
private void inflate() {
    LinearLayout pyramidLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pyramid);

    for (int row = 1 ; row <= mSize; ++row) {
        View rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
        for (int column = 1; column <= row; ++column) {
            View btnView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.btn, null);
            Button btn = (Button) btnView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setId(row*10 + column);
            rowLayout.addView(btnView);
        }
        pyramidLayout.addView(rowView); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In btn.xml, change **layout_width="50dip"** to **width="50dip"**.

Comment: yeah, that's all it was.  Thanks

Comment: Great Rick, perfect explanation. I couln't get the hang  of dynamic inflation. And now it's working!!

tanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for this tutorial. It really helps me :)
In my case, I have a view (2 texts, 1 image, 1 button) who represents 1 result.
When the user click on "search" I need to display it many time. So your example was perferct for me